# Are there any good automated tools to document REST APIs

Tags: json, wcf, rest

Are there any automated tools that I can point to our WCF REST API and have it create documentation (preferably with samples)?

Comment: Not an answer to your question as you are looking for .net solution, but for java, this works great for me: http://enunciate.codehaus.org

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the Sandcastle project.  We're using it to produce MSDN or JavaDoc style Html pages based on the `///<summary>` tags on our public C# members.

http://sandcastle.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 2):

Are you using Web Api?  If so the following link could help

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/yaohuang1/archive/2012/05/13/asp-net-web-api-introducing-iapiexplorer-apiexplorer.aspx

Here is something on general documentation.
http://blog.programmableweb.com/2010/08/12/web-api-documentation-best-practices/

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [Rest Assured library](https://code.google.com/p/rest-assured/).
For demo with sample script, refer to http://artoftesting.com/automationTesting/restAPIAutomationGetRequest.html

Answer (score 0):

Try [Swagger](http://swagger.io).

Maybe the best **open source** solution at the moment. It has a lot of tools available for REST API documentation and more.