# Build XML documentation by code

Tags: c#, xml

I try to write a litte plugin for Visual studio for XML code documenation.
But my code that creates the XML is not working correctly:

```
XElement rootElement = new XElement("doc");
XElement summaryElement = new XElement("summary");

var refElement = new XElement("see");
refElement.Add(new XAttribute("cref", codeFunction.Name));
summaryElement.Value = string.Format("Initializes a new instance of the {0} class.", seeRefElement);
rootElement.Add(summaryElement);
comment = rootElement.ToString();
```

This is the output.

> ```
> <doc>\r\n  <summary>Initializes a new instance of the &lt;see cref="Form1" /&gt; class.</summary>\r\n</doc>
> ```

It should be:

> ```
> <doc>\r\n  <summary>Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="Form1" />class.</summary>\r\n</doc>
> ```

Should I use another way to create my XML?Any hints and improvments are appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Substitute following line

```
summaryElement.Value = string.Format("Initializes a new instance of the {0} class.", refElement);
```

with

```
summaryElement.Add(new XText("Initializes a new instance of the "));
summaryElement.Add(refElement);
summaryElement.Add(new XText(" class."));
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. Would you recommand the `XElements`, a `XmlDocument` or `XmlWriter`?

Comment: For your scenario, I think LINQ to XML is more appropriate choice. You may also look at this questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1542073/xdocument-or-xmldocument , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660377/xmldocument-vs-xmlwriter

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's escaping the < as a matter of course.  There's a thread elsewhere about this, with some suggested workarounds:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharplanguage/thread/413654f3-dc2d-4b96-8a7e-bde69da05866

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to generate API docs from the summary XML is to use Sandcastle. See this thread for links: [Are there any good automated tools to document REST APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12535410/are-there-any-good-automated-tools-to-document-rest-apis)